Bad gateway with traefik
I have this error in my log: "502 Bad Gateway' caused by: dial tcp 172.20.0.3:8012: connect: connection refused."
I check my file acme.json and it's correct.
I don't understand why...
My docker-compose seems correct to me.
My application listen on 8012 and I configure Traefik to redirect on 80.
My docker-compose is:
services:
  proxy:
    container_name: test-proxy
    image: traefik:v2.11
    command:
      - --log.level=debug
      - --providers.docker=true
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
      - --entryPoints.websecure.address=:443
      - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
      - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.to=websecure
      - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.scheme=https
      - --certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.tlschallenge=true
      - --certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.email=f.******@gmail.com
      - --certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - proxy-data:/letsencrypt
    networks:
      - reseau-proxy
    labels:
      # Labels pour shop.******.com
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.shop.rule=Host(`shop.domainname.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.shop.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.shop.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt"
      - "traefik.http.routers.shop.service=shop-service"
      - "traefik.http.services.shop-service.loadbalancer.server.port=8012"
      # Labels pour test.nomdedomaine.com
      - "traefik.http.routers.test.rule=Host(`test.domainname.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.test.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.test.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt"
      - "traefik.http.routers.test.middlewares=redirect-to-shop"
      # Middleware pour la redirection
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-shop.redirectregex.regex=.*"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-shop.redirectregex.replacement=https://shop.domainname.com"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-shop.redirectregex.permanent=true"
  test_web:
      build:
        context: ./test 
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      container_name: test-web
      ports:
          - "8012:80"         
      restart: unless-stopped
      labels:
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.http.routers.test-web.rule=Host(`shop.domainname.com`)"
        - "traefik.http.routers.test-web.entrypoints=websecure"
        - "traefik.http.routers.test-web.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt"
        - "traefik.http.routers.test-web.service=test-service"
        - "traefik.http.services.test-service.loadbalancer.server.port=8012"
        - "traefik.docker.network=test_reseau-proxy"
      environment:
        ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: ${ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT}          
      volumes:
        - test_data:/app/App_Data
      networks:
        - reseau-interne
        - reseau-proxy
      expose:
        - "8012"
  networks:
    reseau-interne:
      driver: bridge
    reseau-proxy:
      driver: bridge

